# windows xp automatically remove temporary profiles on logoff

Tags: windows-xp, login, samba, user-profiles

I am partly managing a school which uses temporary local profiles. (NOT server-saved profiles). The computers are automatically getting restored regularly, but inbetween alot of temporary profiles gather on the computers, sometimes even completely filling up the hard drives, which turns to a real problem then.

How can I automatically delete the profile when a user logs out?

**Edit:**
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\DeleteRoamingCache` does only remove those "server-saved" roaming profiles.
Also, deleting the profiles just on startup using delprof or such is a sub-optimal solution which I would rather not like to use. It should be removed just when logging out.

Answer (score 0):

You can make them [Mandatory profiles](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307800).
This should erase them after they log off.